# 21-04783-85013 outputs as 2.83544E+11 in my PHP array output (read from CSV)

Tags: php, arrays, formatting

---

### EDIT: It was my error, I was looking at the wrong line in the CSV, this question no longer needs an answer.

As per title when I output my array I get funny numbers like 2.83544E+11 (when in this case it should have been 21-04783-85013.) I've tried looking this up an believe it could be something to do with the CSV encoding? with that in mind i tried `mb_convert_encoding($fileRow[20], 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8'),` to no avail.

Here is the complete code

```
function readCSV($csvFile)
{
    $output = [];
    $fileHandle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    $header = fgetcsv($fileHandle);
    while (!feof($fileHandle)) {
        $fileRow = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 1024);
        $orderId = $fileRow[0];
        // skip this row if it's empty (the first field contains no id)
        if (empty($orderId)) {
            continue;
        }
        /*
          $fileRow[3] is "Buyer name", the first field that's present in one type of row
          (the one containing common properties of the order). By checking if it's empty,
          we identify the contents of the row - not empty means order row with common
          properties, empty means item row with specific item properties.
         */
        if (!empty($fileRow[3])) {
            // no need to repeat the id inside the array - it's already stored in the key
            $output[$orderId] = [
                'order_number' => $fileRow[0],
                'buyer_username' => $fileRow[2],
                'buyer_name' => $fileRow[3],
                // here you can continue explicitly adding any property you need
            ];
        } else {
            // add a new item entry
            $output[$orderId]['items'][] = [
                'item_number' => $fileRow[20],
                'item_title' => $fileRow[21],
                'quantity' => $fileRow[24],
                'price' => $fileRow[25],
                // here you can continue explicitly adding any property you need
            ];
        }
    }
    fclose($fileHandle);
    return $output;
}
    // Set path to CSV file
    $csvFile = 'tmp_csv_store/my.csv';
    $csv = readCSV($csvFile);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';
```

It seems to be this line `'item_number' => $fileRow[20],` i need to format? Suggestions if you would plase?

EDIT to add..

Output from php result..

```
[item_number] => 2.83544E+11
```

Output from result in question on CSV file (from notepad)

```
110393,21-04783-85013,wend,WENDY ,wendy@no-email.com,,10 ANY Road,Northfield,Birmingham,West Midlands,B11 1BB, //LINE CONTINUES (second item is the problem)
```

Expected output

```
[item_number] => 21-04783-85013
```

Comment: Can you show the raw output of the line in question (so via a text editor), I wonder if it may be the way you view the file?

Comment: @NigelRen Updated OP to show requested info

Comment: in the result of print_r($csv);

Comment: Where you show that line, the value it is picking up from is position 20, I assume the data in question is being fetched from subsequent lines.

Comment: @NigelRen apologies, on further inspection I was looking at the wrong CSV line, its actually in the CSV its wrong! Whats the correct proceedure now, do i edit the question to ask how to convert 2.83544E+11 to the number I need as it seems like this questions is completly wrong now or should i delete the question and ask a new one?

Comment: Up to you, but completely changing the question may be confusing for others.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the OP to show this question no longer needs an answer. Thanks for your help.